# TYPO3 News Extension Pagionation doesn't work

Tags: typo3

I use the news extension in TYPO3 and so far it's almost fine.

The only problem I have is the pagination. If I click e.g. on the pagination page 2, the link get some extra string like `&tx_news_pi1[%40widget_0][currentPage]=2` but the outcome is always the same like on the first page. So do I have to do something in the settings to get this working or does anyone of you have an idea where the mistake could be?

I looked up at github and google but couldn't find any helpful information for my problem which is kind of unbelievable...

Another thing is I would try to do an AJAX pagination when it's working. I saw the topic on the TYPO3 site (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/Templates/AjaxBasedPagination/Index.html) and followed the instructions of installing typoscript_rendering, inserting the list plugin as content element, changed the template path and inserted the js.file. But the thing here is when I set the template path to the indexAjax.html I get the following error

`Undeclared arguments passed to ViewHelper GeorgRinger\\News\\ViewHelpers\\Widget\\Ajax\\PaginateAdditionalParamsViewHelper: page`

When I look in the AjaxPagination.js given by link above the variable `ajaxUrl` is always undefined, because it wants to grab the data which causes the error message above I think. Hopefully somebody of you can hint me to the right solution..

Comment: I am not completely sure, but it could be a setting based on what version you are using (?). If you're using the latest version of 'news', there are settings in the plugin options that say: "exclude already displayed news", "maximum records" and "records per page" - or something similar. Try to disable "exclude already displayed news", empty "maximum records" and set "records per page" to something low.

Comment: Using TYPO 9.1.0 and news 6.3.0. All you mentioned was already set in my config. When I click on the second page, I realise that the set active part in the pagination doesn't work too.

Comment: Any other suggestions maybe?